# How to send commands to running CMD instance

Tags: cmd

On Windows 10 I have a special developer command prompt (**DevEnv**). Every time another program (Matlab) creates a file output, I have to run a command in this command prompt to start another process:

1. `myDevEnv.bat` (sets environment variables, starts server instances, ...)
2. Matlab script creates `myFile.foo`
3. In **DevEnv**: `doSomethingWithFiles.bat myFile.foo`

I would like Matlab to call the third command from within the **DevEnv**. So my idea was to write the commands to a file, that is permanently read and executed in the **DevEnv**. Is this possible in a Windows command prompt?